# Build a matrix of available actions for Q-Learning

Tags: numpy, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am simulating an inventory management system for a retail shop; therefore, I have a (15,15) matrix of zeros in which states are rows and actions columns:

```
Q = np.matrix(np.zeros([15, 15]) )
```

Specifically, 0 is the minimum and 14 the maximum inventory level, states are current inventory level and actions stock orders (quantity).

Consequently, I would like to substitute zeros with "-1", where the sum of state and action > 14:

```
print(final_Q)

#First row, from which I can order everything (since 0 + 14 == 14)
[[0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
#Second row, from which I can order max. 13 products (1 + 14 > 14)
[[0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1]]
#Third row, from which the max is 12    
[[0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1]]

(...)
```

I tried implementing that manually, but how can I get the **final** **matrix** automatically?

Comment: do you just want a lower triangular matrix?

Comment: Ecaxtly, but it should start from the end, as explained in the matrix of the post. @Attack68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Q = np.tril(-1*np.ones(15), -1)[:, ::-1]

>>> Q
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.]])
```

Comment: it is correct; just added np.asmatrix before the formula.

Comment: From numpy docs regarding `matrix`: "It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future."

Answer (score 1):

```
# Q matrix
Q = np.matrix(np.zeros([15+1, 15+1] ))

# Create a diagonal of -1s
Q = Q[0:15][0:15]
il1 = np.tril_indices(15)
Q[il1] = -1
Q = np.rot90(Q)

# Adjust single values
Q[parameters["max_products"]-1][0, 1:] = Q[parameters["max_products"]][0, 1:]
Q = Q[:15, :]
```

It is definitely not computationally effective but it works.